# Toshiba laptop display horizontal lines - disappear in seconds

Tags: windows-8, display, toshiba-laptop

I recently bought Toshiba Satellite S55-A5257. I am facing a small glitch.
Sometimes, a horizontal line(it has been only 1 so far) appears across display. The line is not black but some weird RGB combination. It disappears in a few seconds(or may be after I move my cursor), and the display returns to normal.

I have typically observed this behavior on Windows login screen and sometimes after logging in.

What could be the issue? I doubt it's a hardware problem because in that case the line would have stayed there. And btw, I don't have to move display back and forth to fix the problem, so it's not a connector cable issue.

As far as graphics is concerned, mine has Intel HD graphics that comes with Core i7-4700MQ.
And Toshiba center says that the drivers are up to date and my Windows is up to date.

It's not that this problem is bothering me much but as the old saying goes, a stitch in time saves nine.

Comment: Can you determine whether it disappears on it's own, or whether it disappears after you move the cursor?  Disappearing after you move the cursor would most likely mean that the issue was software... and disappearing on it's own could still mean it is hardware (regardless of whether or not you believe it is hardware).  For example, a line on the screen that appears and disappears when you move the screen isn't actually caused by a cable issue, it is caused by a screen that has been twisted too often by being opened at one corner instead of at the center top.

Comment: @BonGart: I'll have to experiment a li'l bit...fortunately, it does not yet happen that frequently..